# How to reuse UIObjects from one class to multiple classes using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am trying to programmatically create (without using `xib` and `storyboard`) universal  application with complicated custom `tableview`, `buttons`, etc,,,

Now the problem is I need to create all the objects one time into single class file and reuse it multiple class and multiple device constraints. Please help me and give me good examples for my questions.

I think If I can create reusability methods its reducing app memory and increasing app performance little bit moreover others can easily understand my code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is exactly your problem? Is it a design problem or a coding problem? Why do you have the 'single file' constraint?

Comment: Right now I am creating multiple UIObjects Multiple times, but I want to create single time into one common class and reuse it everywhere. Same time I am making different device constraints also, for that If u have any Idea let me know here!@tomsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that this is wise or advisable to do, because I thing that element that will be add to the screen will not take so much time to render and because when screen go off screen it will release all of the element so it won't take much memory. If you have multiple (same) element on one screen, then you would have to have multiple copies of this object so you in any case don't save any cash space.

This approach is reasonable where you change a lot of object of same tip, like cells in UITableView, or ImageView in gallery.... In this case you create one class that contains reusable object and they are not universally created.

But to answer your question.

What you could do is subclass all of your UI object, and initialize them into AppDelegate class as properties

AppDelegate is "universal" class that is always created, and all other classes can have access to it.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Comment: I think your great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should create separate instance of those custom ui objects in different UIViewController as re-using 'same view instance' inside different view controller classes will break the view hierarchy as same ui-instance can only have one superview. So you can't re-use the same custom view instance in multiple places. Better implement the low memory methods and use difference instance inside different container(or UIViewController).